# Set up Ubuntu server as router

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, ubuntu-server, network-interface

I just installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server on a old desktop PC with a dual port network card I would like to use as router for my home network. How do I have to set up the interfaces so that the internet connection is passed through the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step when configuring Linux as a router is to enable IP forwarding:

```
$ echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Now the OS can route packets between interfaces.

Next use `iptables` and *netfilter* to create traffic rules.

I would suggest that you use a front-end to `iptables` and *Netfilter* in order to configure your router and manage the interface rules and policies.

If you prefer a GUI then see some of the other helpful answers on this page.

If you would like to hack at the command line and experience the true power of the Force, then try the excellent [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net/) front-end to `iptables` and *netfilter* which will allow you to easily configure your router straight away. Yet, as you learn more about routing Shorewall will allow increasingly fine-grained configurations and packet level network flow control.

The shorewall package is available in the Ubuntu repositories (choose either the shell or Perl package). The Shorewall site has great documentation and helpful tutorials for a multitude of scenarios. The basic 2- or 3- interface [examples](http://shorewall.net/GettingStarted.html) should get you going.

Comment: I'm trying to set up shorewall as well.  If I follow this approach, do I need to set up all NIC's in /etc/network/interfaces first?  The shorewall docs simply don't mention it at all.  Some other tutorials do show it.  I spent a couple hours yesterday trying to get 12.04 happy with this file and gave up after playing the rebooting guessing game basically ruled out everything I tried.   (I tried some router distros but I need something complex.)

Comment: @Paul Ubuntu's Network Manager is probably trying to control those NICs and overwriting the */etc/network/interfaces* and */etc/resolv.conf* files. Yes, you will have to configure the NICs at OS level prior to configuring shorewall. I suggest you install ubuntu-server distro or uninstall network-manager

Comment: this should help (with or without NM): <http://askubuntu.com/questions/196640/how-to-change-ip-when-etc-network-interface-file-is-missing>

Comment: @Paul mind sharing what the issue turned out to be and how you solved it (briefly) ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what I was doing wrong;  I set up a new Ubuntu 12.04 in a new VM and things worked more smoothly.  The final /etc/interfaces file I used is documented in another [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/324901/setting-up-etc-network-interfaces-for-sandboxed-network-with-12-04-lts?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/). Have a read on [iptables over on the Ubuntu community site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo). You could also use something like [firestarter](http://www.fs-security.com/) for a nicer GUI experience.

Personally, I would recommend using a dedicated gateway distro such as ipcop, m0n0wall or an all-in-one system like ClearOS or Untangle. It would simplify the management of the firewall as well as offer you quite a few other features (also, with simplicity built in).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only problem I have at the moment is that the other network interfaces (three in total, two on the two port network card and one integrated into the mainboard) are not listed under `/etc/network/interfaces`. How can I get them to be listed? They were correctly shown during setup of Ubuntu.

Comment: @wowpatrick I think it would work to your advantage to make a whole new question since that's completely different than the question posted above. Try the Ubuntu Stack Exchange site: http://askubuntu.com/